# 404 Method not found in postman

Tags: postman, google-my-business-api

When I try to get the google my business account number using postman I got the 404 method not found error

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**What I'm missing ??**

Comment: You must be hitting the wrong endpoint. It's definitely not an issue with Postman

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to postman . your URL is wrong.

google document say that this api is [**deprecated**](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/get).

> Method: accounts.get
>
> Deprecated. Please use the **Account Management API** instead.